# Sending ICMP packets in a C program

Tags: c, ping, icmp, sendto

I'm trying to create an ICMP ping test program in C but am having difficulties with successfully sending the packets.  The `sendto` function returns the # of bytes and everything but no packets are actually sent.  I've verified this with WireShark on the destination computer. A regular ping on the host works fine and shows up in WireShark though.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/in_systm.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

unsigned short cksum(unsigned short *addr, int len);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    char send_buf[400], recv_buf[400], src_name[256], src_ip[15], dst_ip[15];
    struct ip *ip = (struct ip *)send_buf;
    struct icmp *icmp = (struct icmp *)(ip + 1);
    struct hostent *src_hp, *dst_hp;
    struct sockaddr_in src, dst;
    struct timeval t;
    int on;
    int num = 10;
    int failed_count = 0;
    int bytes_sent, bytes_recv;
    int dst_addr_len;
    int result;
    fd_set socks;

    /* Initialize variables */
    on = 1;
    memset(send_buf, 0, sizeof(send_buf));

    /* Check for valid args */
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("\nUsage: %s <dst_server>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("- dst_server is the target\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Check for root access */
    if (getuid() != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: This program requires root privileges!\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Get source IP address */
    if(gethostname(src_name, sizeof(src_name)) < 0)
    {
        perror("gethostname() error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        if((src_hp = gethostbyname(src_name)) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Can't resolve, unknown source.\n", src_name);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
            ip->ip_src = (*(struct in_addr *)src_hp->h_addr);
    }

    /* Get destination IP address */
    if((dst_hp = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL)
    {
        if((ip->ip_dst.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1])) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Can't resolve, unknown destination.\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ip->ip_dst = (*(struct in_addr *)dst_hp->h_addr);
        dst.sin_addr = (*(struct in_addr *)dst_hp->h_addr);
    }
    
    sprintf(src_ip, "%s", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
    sprintf(dst_ip, "%s", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_dst));
    printf("Source IP: '%s' -- Destination IP: '%s'\n", src_ip, dst_ip);

    /* Create RAW socket */
    if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket() error");

        /* If something wrong, just exit */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Socket options, tell the kernel we provide the IP structure */
    if(setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt() for IP_HDRINCL error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* IP structure, check the ip.h */
    ip->ip_v = 4;
    ip->ip_hl = 5;
    ip->ip_tos = 0;
    ip->ip_len = htons(sizeof(send_buf));
    ip->ip_id = htons(321);
    ip->ip_off = htons(0);
    ip->ip_ttl = 255;
    ip->ip_p = IPPROTO_ICMP;
    ip->ip_sum = 0;

    /* ICMP structure, check ip_icmp.h */
    icmp->icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;
    icmp->icmp_code = 0;
    icmp->icmp_id = 123;
    icmp->icmp_seq = 0;
    
    /* Set up destination address family */
    dst.sin_family = AF_INET;
    
    /* Loop based on the packet number */
    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        /* Header checksums */
        icmp->icmp_cksum = 0;
        ip->ip_sum = cksum((unsigned short *)send_buf, ip->ip_hl);
        icmp->icmp_cksum = cksum((unsigned short *)icmp,
                           sizeof(send_buf) - sizeof(struct icmp));
        
        /* Get destination address length */
        dst_addr_len = sizeof(dst);
        
        /* Set listening timeout */
        t.tv_sec = 5;
        t.tv_usec = 0;
    
        /* Set socket listening descriptors */
        FD_ZERO(&socks);
        FD_SET(sock, &socks);
        
        /* Send packet */
        if((bytes_sent = sendto(sock, send_buf, sizeof(send_buf), 0,
                         (struct sockaddr *)&dst, dst_addr_len)) < 0)
        {
            perror("sendto() error");
            failed_count++;
            printf("Failed to send packet.\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Sent %d byte packet... ", bytes_sent);
            
            fflush(stdout);
            
            /* Listen for the response or timeout */
            if((result = select(sock + 1, &socks, NULL, NULL, &t)) < 0)
            {
                perror("select() error");
                failed_count++;
                printf("Error receiving packet!\n");
            }
            else if (result > 0)
            {
                printf("Waiting for packet... ");
                fflush(stdout);
                
                if((bytes_recv = recvfrom(sock, recv_buf,
                     sizeof(ip) + sizeof(icmp) + sizeof(recv_buf), 0,
                     (struct sockaddr *)&dst,
                     (socklen_t *)&dst_addr_len)) < 0)
                {
                    perror("recvfrom() error");
                    failed_count++;
                    fflush(stdout);
                }
                else
                    printf("Received %d byte packet!\n", bytes_recv);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Failed to receive packet!\n");
                failed_count++;
            }
            
            fflush(stdout);
            
            icmp->icmp_seq++;
        }
    }
    
    /* Display success rate */
    printf("Ping test completed with %d%% success rate.\n",
           (((num - failed_count) / num) * 100));
    
    /* close socket */
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}

/* One's Complement checksum algorithm */
unsigned short cksum(unsigned short *addr, int len)
{
    int nleft = len;
    int sum = 0;
    unsigned short *w = addr;
    unsigned short answer = 0;

    while (nleft > 1)
    {
      sum += *w++;
      nleft -= 2;
    }

    if (nleft == 1)
    {
      *(unsigned char *)(&answer) = *(unsigned char *)w;
      sum += answer;
    }

    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    answer = ~sum;
    
    return (answer);
}
```

Any thoughts at what I'm doing wrong?  Also, are the checksums alright?  Is it fine to just use 0 for both?

**EDIT:** OK, so I've managed to get the packets sent properly thanks to the folks below!  And the destination computer will send back an echo reply.  However, now, my program doesn't pick up the reply.  The `select()` function always times out. I've updated my code above.

**EDIT 2:** Alright, I've got it working! I needed to set the socket protocol to `IPPROTO_ICMP` instead of `IPPROTO_RAW` and it worked great!  Thanks again you guys that commented!  Really helped out!  Looks like I can only mark one answer correct, but you all aided in fixing this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just one thing that I've noticed...

You've got this:

```
 struct ip *ip = (struct ip *)send_buf;
```

Then, you are assigning destination field:

```
ip->ip_dst = (*(struct in_addr *)dst_hp->h_addr)
```

And then you are erasing it with memset (since send_buff points to the same thing):

```
memset(send_buf, 0, sizeof(send_buf));
```

So, when you are trying to get ip_dst here:

```
dst.sin_addr = ip->ip_dst;
```

you are getting 0 instead of what you set earlier.

Comment: Thanks, I completely overlooked that!  I moved the memset call towards the top and now I can see the packets coming in from WireShark.  It comes in as a ping echo request but no replies are sent back to the host and the select call times out.  Any clue why?

Answer (score 2):

At first glance: You can't rely on time struct after select().
You should also set usec.

So in the code, include the specification of t values inside the for loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    t.tv_sec = 5;
    t.tv_usec = 0;
    ...
```

Else when you get on second iteration t (can have) changed.

In your sprintf(src_ip, ...) and dst_ip you have omitted format.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ebutusov's reply:

```
ip->ip_sum = 0;
icmp->icmp_cksum = htons(~(ICMP_ECHO << 8));
```

Are both incorrect.
You need to calculate the checksum properly (it's the same algorithm for both, but covers different fields).

Comment: Yup, calculating the checksum correctly fixed the problem! The echo replies are sent back. But the select function times out even with the reply.  Something's wrong with that setup...

Comment: You didn't bind your socket. So the OS has no reason to pass the ICMP reply to you. In a raw socket, it doesn't look at what you send, so it has no way to know that the received ICMP is a reply to it.